# Is that the correct way of creating realm module?

Tags: android, realm

Hi i have a android project that use another android project as a module. I used realm for offline data storage. both the project uses realm data base. when i try to run the project it shows error.

```
 class RealmModel is not part of the schema for this Realm
```

i used this [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4616) to fix that error

In that above url, they asked to create RealmModule class with @RealmModule annotation. This is my class,

```
 @RealmModule
 public class MessageRealmModule implements RealmModule {

     @Override
     public boolean library() {
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean allClasses() {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public Class<?>[] classes() {
         return new Class<?>[0];
     }

     @Override
     public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

After this line got this error.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.anubavam.message.MessageRealmModule is not a RealmModule. Add @RealmModule to the class definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you need to do it in the annotation parameters like so:

```
@RealmModule(library = true, classes = { MyModelClass.class })
public class MessageRealmModule {
}
```

See also https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas

Comment: Also i removed library = true, now also its working. can you tell me why its must to add "library = true".

Comment: You only need that if you are using Realm in a library project. This is so the code generated by the library doesn't conflict with the main app project.